# pod to services communication not Working - rke kubernetes on centos 8

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, coredns, rke

I deployed an RKE cluster on CentOS 8 with 3 nodes.

The installation was successful but figured out that pod cannot resolve external URL because the ClusterIP of CoreDNS is not reachable.

Only pod to pod communication works.

I checked iptables rules for each Cluster IP entry and they exist.

What could be the root cause of this issue? Any hints?

Comment: Could you share your [configuration of the RKE cluster](https://rancher.com/docs/rke/latest/en/installation/#creating-the-cluster-configuration-file)? Which [CNI plugin](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/faq/networking/cni-providers/#what-cni-providers-are-provided-by-rancher) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Change the configuration file: /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 1
```

Source: https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/1879#issuecomment-398679334

Comment: I have already done this steps but still have the issue,

Comment: Also i ve set FELIX_IPTABLESBACKEND=nft and also blacklisted the ip_tables module. 
Firewalld is disabled too. but still have the issue,
any hints please ?